# Is there any way to capture the scrolling on a tray icon in pyside6 and give a value?

Tags: python, user-interface, mouseevent, pyside6, python-3.11

I'm trying to find a way to capture the scrolling of the mouse/trackpad on a trayicon in pyside6 and to make it give out a value from 0 to 100 based on how much did you scroll. I'm trying to recreate something like what kde does when you scroll on the speaker icon which changes the volume from 1 to 100.

I tried to capture the scroll with qscroller and with a delta value but they didn't change. I'm not sure if qscroller works since it captures the mouse and i'm on wayland which doesn't allow capturing the mouse.

Comment: The documentation states that Qt only provides *wheel events* (not *scroll* events, which are related but different event types) and on X11 only. In any case, you should override `event()` and look for `Wheel` event, as the documentation states, did you actually try that?